# Accessing another library from tinyMCE

Tags: jquery, ajax, upload, tinymce

I'm trying to add a button that can upload images to a given directory in the advimage plugin in tinyMCE.
I'm using http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ to upload files.

The upload script and the button work well from a common page.
I then edit \advimage\image.htm and add div for the components :

```
<div id="img_uploader"></div>
```

I edited the \advimage\js\image.js and added the following at the end of the edit function :

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
  element: document.getElementById('img_uploader'),
  action: '/Admin/Uploader.ashx'
```

});

When I execute it, I get a '**qq is not defined**'

My libraries are included with a ScriptManager :

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
  <Scripts>                
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/uploadify/fileuploader.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" />                
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/Ain.js" />
  </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Any help welcome !!!
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't notice the top of image.htm and the fact that it is a proper html page with html, head, body tags...
I just have to add the proper libraries there and it works !